# PrimeNG Calendar showing plus icon instead of next icon

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, primeng, primeicons, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I am using PrimeNG Calendar in my web application, and I have encountered an issue where the calendar displays a plus icon instead of the expected next icon.

Class and icon used by component >
class="ui-datepicker-next-icon pi pi-chevron-right ng-tns-c151-2"

[Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpyMe.png)

The PrimeNG Calendar should display a next icon, allowing users to navigate to the next month.

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxEBz.png)

```
<p-calendar
  styleClass="startDateCalender"
  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
  appendTo="body"
  [showIcon]="true"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  formControlName="startDate"
  [(ngModel)]="startDateValue"
  required
  [minDate]="minDate"
  [maxDate]="maxDate"
  readonly="true"
  [defaultDate]="minDate"
></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.